# Сохранить результат цикла в массив JAVA

Tags: java

Доброе утро дорогие коллеги. Объясните пожалуйста как записать результат цикла в новый массив:

```
    String text = "absdsbad";
    char[] array = text.toCharArray();
    
    char[] arrayToChar = new char[array.length];
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(arrayToChar);
```

хочу записать этот результат в массив arrayToChar
тут как бы идет реверс. знаю что могу воспользоваться StringBuilder и сделать реверс но нужно именно из цикла записать результат.
Спасибо за помощь!

Благодарю всех за отлик и за помощь!
Идея изначально была такая что бы сравнить два массива на правду.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "abccba";

        char[] array1 = text.toCharArray();
        char[] array2 = new char[array1.length];

        boolean result = false;
        
        for (int i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array2[array1.length - i - 1] = array1[i];
            result = Arrays.equals(array1,array2);
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

сейчас у меня вот так проверяет результат.  Но мне нужно что бы результат проверялся без метода equals и сделать проверку в этом же цикле (если это возможно) =)
Всем еще раз спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На что вы хотите сделать проверку? Массив `array2` при создании заполняется символами-нулями `'\0'`, поэтому вызов `Arrays.equals` до окончания цикла не имеет смысла совсем.  После окончания цикла `Arrays.equals` вернёт `true` только в случае полного палиндрома.

Comment: Я хочу сделать проверку если текст читается одинаково с левой стороны и с правой то на выходе true или же false если не проходит проверку.
absdsba = true
Qajtiglq = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи нет особой необходимости *дополнительно* создавать новый массив символов, так как по умолчанию метод [`String::toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) копирует содержимое строки в новый массив:

> `public char[] toCharArray()`
> Converts this string to a new character array.
> **Returns:**
> a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

Соответственно, для инвертирования строки можно будет использовать массив `array`, причём это можно сделать эффективно за `n/2` итераций, обменивая поочерёдно первый элемент с последним, второй с предпоследним и так далее до середины массива.  Обмен значений между двумя элементами массива можно выполнять как с помощью вспомогательного символа, так и без него.

***Дополнение:***
Также можно сразу реализовать проверку, является ли входная строка полным палиндромом, поочерёдно проверяя пары символов и применяя логическое AND:

```java
String text = "absdsbad";
char[] array = text.toCharArray();
boolean isPalindrome = true; // предполагаем что палиндром существует

// обмен попроще, один индекс и вспомогательная переменная
for (int i = 0, n = array.length; i < n / 2; i++) {
    char c = array[i];
    isPalindrome &= c == array[n - i - 1]; // сравниваем два символа

    array[i] = array[n - i - 1];
    array[n - i - 1] = c;
}
System.out.println(array); // -> dabsdsba
System.out.println("palindrome? " + isPalindrome); // -> palindrome? false

isPalindrome = true;

// обмен с двумя индексами
for (int i = 0, j = array.length; i < --j;) {
    isPalindrome &= array[i] == array[j];

    array[i] = (char)(array[i] ^ array[j] ^ (array[j] = array[i++]));
}
System.out.println(array); // -> absdsbad
System.out.println("palindrome? " + isPalindrome); // -> palindrome? false
```

Для входной строки `String text = "abccba";` результат будет такой:

```
abccba
palindrome? true
abccba
palindrome? true
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! идея изначально была другая что бы потом сравнить два массива на Arrays.equals. Теперь не знаю как правильно их сравнить без метода equals. как в цикле сразу сравнить элементы на правду в цикле? 
 for (int i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array2[array1.length - i - 1] = array1[i];
            result = Arrays.equals(array1,array2);
        }
Сейчас у меня так а я хочу без метода equals прям в цикле. и на выходе true или false.

Comment: Вы хотите странного.  Во-первых, массивы будут заведомо не равны, так как _в общем случае_ они будут содержать противоположно направленные последовательности символов.  К тому же сравнение **массивов** _в цикле_ при создании дополнительного массива ещё более бессмысленно, так как этот массив будет содержать `n` нулевых символов `'\0'`, и этот массив будет заполняться постепенно.

Comment: @S0tn1k, добавил проверку на палиндром

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "absdsbad";
char[] array = text.toCharArray();
char[] arrayToChar = new char[text.length()];

for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arrayToChar[array.length - i -1] = array[i];
}
System.out.println(arrayToChar);
```